# What is an extremely lightweight way to detect change in an image?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, images, camera

I'm trying to find the most lightweight method to detect "adequate" change in an image. I realize that's a terrible constraint, so for the sake of this question I'll break it into two different qualifiers: substantial change, or 80% pixels changed, and motion-changed, or 10% pixels changed. These images are captured via `timelapse` mode on a raspberry pi camera, but for the sake of the question, *the files could be from any basically-static view point*.

I've found that I can use filesize to observe change of substantial amounts:

```
user@host-bb:/tmp$ ls -la investigating/
total 134604
drwxr-xr-x 2 user group    4096 Oct 20 00:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 user group    4096 Oct 20 00:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 4580181 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223300.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 4573449 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223301.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 4573024 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223304.jpg
...snip...
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 4455867 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223320.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 4447607 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223321.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 4434839 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223323.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 4416942 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223324.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 1769008 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223325.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 1702851 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223326.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 1639306 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223327.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 1788435 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223328.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 1908061 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223329.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 1981029 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223330.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 2102390 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223331.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 2167734 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223333.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 2243082 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223334.jpg
...snip...
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 2640732 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223342.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 2730206 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223343.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 2751966 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223344.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  315875 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223345.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  302476 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223352.jpg
...snip...
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  285965 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223358.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  289271 Oct 20 00:05 image1018223359.jpg
user@host-bb:/tmp$
```

Even between somewhat non-major changes in lighting (such as occurred between images `*28.jpg` and `*29.jpg`) can produce a difference in filesize.
I realize this is basically binning, and it could be the solution I'm looking for.
This takes care of the "substantial change" (80% of pixels changed).

The question remains though: Short of Imagemagick, Python script, or other image processing software, is there a lightweight way to detect change in an image that is closer to 10% pixels changed? If there is no non-image-processing software option, what would the most light-weight option be? Writing my own processing in a low-level language? A Python script?
I'm coming from a Python background and am trying to do simple change detection on a raspberry pi zero w that can then trigger an event (file upload) if there is a change. Bandwidth is too small to send all the images, and the pi zero w is not a heavy hitter when it comes to processing power.

Comment: You'd also need to take into account the amount of change for each pixel. The noise from the camera might make even back-to-back images differ significantly if you only look at the number of changed pixels

Comment: @ilkkachu That is true; I'm not saying that the size comparison is a good detector, just that it's a simple one I've found may somewhat work in some cases...

Comment: No, the size difference is definitely an indicator of some change, but not a very discreet one of course. What I meant is that when you said you'd like to detect e.g. 10 % of the pixels changing to detect motion, it's not enough to just detect the _change_, you have to check the magnitude too. And the image size might be too rough an indicator to help there, if the lighting and such remain the same.

Comment: I think Python has some image processing libraries, so it shouldn't be too hard to just make a program to look at the pixels. You seem to have something like 1 image per second, so performance shouldn't be an issue. I mean, I'm not sure, but I doubt even the Pi zero is that slow...

Answer (score 2):

1) Very very basic (but very lightweight): using cmp and to compare the files byte by byte ("binary diff"). Gives the amount of different bytes. I just tried on a zero, works.

```
cmp -l 1.jpg 2.jpg 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

but, it's more file related than image-wise...

Therefore, if you have access to Python on your machine (sorry I don't have the same distribution on my rpi zero so I can't test...):

2) SSIM-PIL Python package, based on Structural SIMilarity. (https://pypi.org/project/SSIM-PIL/). Is image oriented so compared to solution one, it should give less "false differences", meaning the result will be closer to what the human eye sees. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_Similarity